# Erro ao carregar linguagem do CodeIgniter Rest Server

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

Eu estou codificando uma API com CodeIgniter e, como muitos me recomendaram, estou usando a biblioteca **CodeIgniter Rest Server**([Repositório](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver)). Eu segui o tutorial recomendado pelo próprio desenvolvedor mas eu recebi um erro. O problema acontece quando eu faço require do arquivo **REST_Controller.php**, em alguma parte do script ele tenta fazer a leitura da linguagem e falha dizendo que não conseguiu fazer a leitura do arquivo. Eu coloquei o arquivo de linguagem nas pastas application e system.

No arquivo **config.php** eu tenho isso:

```
$config['language'] = 'english';
```

Esses são os paths de ambos os diretórios de language:

> application/language/english/rest_controller_lang.php
> system/language/english/rest_controller_lang.php

Este é o erro:

> Unable to load the requested language file: language/english/rest_controller_lang.php

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no arquivo: application/config/rest.php, veja como está a variável $config['rest_language']. No caso do inglês, deverá estar como "$config['rest_language'] = 'english'".

Comment: Sim, está exatamente desse jeito.